# How to access MTP device (e.g. GoPro) through python on windows

Tags: python, windows, mtp, gopro

I'm trying to access a GoPro camera storage via the MTP interface on Windows using Python. I found two options that both do no work:

1. pymtp: it needs a mtp dll library that I cannot find, so it fails here:

   _module_path = ctypes.util.find_library("mtp")

   _libmtp = ctypes.CDLL(_module_path)
2. wmdlib, which fails as it cannot find ctypes>=1.0.2:

> No local packages or download links found for ctypes>=1.0.2 error:
>   Could not find suitable distribution for
>   Requirement.parse('ctypes>=1.0.2')

(An windows installer that works for ctypes-1.0.2 does not work either)

Do you know any other options to retrieve my GoPro storage via python on windows?